# Procedurally generate with different sized cubes

Tags: unity

I am trying to procedurally generate my world like in Minecraft with tons of blocks. I have watched lots of videos about this but they all use a single fixed size cube. I would like to achieve the same as in Minecraft but with different sized cubed for example. How could this be done? I am using Perlin Noise for generation.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what exactly your problem is. Could you try to tell us where exactly you are stuck with this?

Comment: Try mocking up an example of the kind of content you want your generator to make. Contrasting "more like this" and "don't generate stuff like that" can help clarify what kinds of output the generator should prefer.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "differently sized cubes"? Do you mean cubes of random size (within some range), or do you mean sizes that are integer multiples of each other (so that they can align nicely), or something else?